# Was wondering why iterating through a dictionary using .keys in django would not work?

Tags: django, django-templates

I know that .items would be useful to grab the value, but wanted to see why this would not work?

Data:

```
...
city_data = {
      'city': json_data['name'],
      'country': json_data['sys']['country'],
      'temp': json_data['main']['temp'],
      'feels_like': json_data['main']['feels_like'],
      'temp_max': json_data['main']['temp_max'],
      'temp_min': json_data['main']['temp_min']
  }
return render(request, ..., context={'city_data':city_data})
```

template:

```
...
  {% for key in city_data.keys %}
    <li>{{city_data.key}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
...
```

Comment: I think it should just work, try: `<li>{{ key }}</li>` ^^

Comment: Right~ 
that works and the keys do show, but wanted to grab the values with {{ key}}

or is that not possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason that it doesn't work that way is because django will look at `test.key` and try to look up a string "key" as an actual key to the dictionary. There are a couple ways that you could do this. One way is you could define a custom template filter that would allow you to do it. I don't know much about custom filters so I can't say how specifically to do it. Another way though is to use `city_data.items` in your template instead like this:

```
{% for key,value in city_data.items %}
   <li>{{ value }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```